# Faceboook oauth redirects to callback without asking for permissions in php

Tags: php, facebook, fb-graph

I am trying to get a list of Facebook pages a user has. When a new user logs into his/her account it asks for pages and permissions later if i update the permissions. Oauth API does'nt ask for permissions but directly redirects to callback as auth url is clicked.

These are permissions i am looking for

```
$perms = ['public_profile','publish_pages','read_insights','manage_pages'];

$connect_url = $helper->getLoginUrl('https://example.com/callback.php', $perms);
```

I am expecting api should ask user for permissions and pages to access for app

Comment: It was issue with developer account. I deleted access token issued to app in developer console & it again asked me for required permissions.